# How to get first_name with Pinterest Javascript SDK?

Tags: javascript, pinterest

I'm able to print `access_token` and `result` array in the console. However, when I'm trying to append the data to a `new Option`, it does not work.

initialize

```
   window.pAsyncInit = function() {
        PDK.init({
            appId: "client_id",
            cookie: false
        });
    };

(function(d, s, id){
    var js, pjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//assets.pinterest.com/sdk/sdk.js";
    pjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, pjs);
}(document, 'script', 'pinterest-jssdk'));
```

auth script

```
function login() {  
//login
PDK.login({ scope : 'read_relationships,read_public,write_public' }, function(response){
if (!response || response.error) {
//  alert('Error occurred');
                } else {
PDK.request('/v1/me/', function (result) {
if (!result || result.error) {
//alert('Error occurred');
              } else {
var access_token = PDK.getSession().accessToken;
console.log(access_token); // works and prints well
console.log(result); // works and prints well

//option works but empty             
pages= new Option(result.data.first_name,access_token).dataset['id'] =result.data.id;

//PDK.logout();
}});
}

});
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the working answer

```
function login() {  
//login
PDK.login({ scope : 'read_relationships,read_public,write_public' }, function(response){
if (!response || response.error) {
//  alert('Error occurred');
                } else {
PDK.request('/v1/me/', function (result) {
if (!result || result.error) {
//alert('Error occurred');
              } else {
     var text = result.data.first_name;
     var value = PDK.getSession().accessToken;
     var additionalData = result.data.id

     //Create the option
     var option = new Option(text, value);
     pages.add(option);

     //create the data-id attribute, add it to the option
     var attribute = document.createAttribute("data-id");
     option.setAttributeNode(attribute);

     //Assign the respective data to the data-id attribute
     option.dataset['id'] = additionalData;

//PDK.logout();
}});
}

});
};
```